# Firebase Realtime Database, how do I know when dataset has finished loading

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

**How do I know when the dataset is loaded?**

I have been using Firebase for over five years and love it. But, I have one question which I hope you can help with, but has been driving me mad for years.

I have many datasets stored on Firebase. What I need is a way to know when the dataset has been loaded. So, if there are 1000 records at the node /Main/PNG/flight/airstrip I want to know when I have received all leaves.

I have tried using **.value** and subscribe to the whole node using

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: key).observe(.value) { [weak self, key] snapshot ...}
```

And then I will know when the dataset comes in because I will get just one snapshot containing a dictionary of all the leaves, but I don't get the deltas (changes and additions).

and I have subscribed to all the leaves, using

```
[.childChanged, .childRemoved, .childAdded].forEach { eventType in
Database.database().reference(withPath: key).observe(eventType) { [weak self, storeEventType] snapshot in ...}
```

But, then I don’t know when I have received all of the dataset.

My datamodel is based on an Initial Snapshot followed by listening to any changes to the leaves. The initial snapshot is easy using

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: key).observe(.value) { [weak self, key] snapshot ...}
```

but when I follow this with

```
[.childChanged, .childRemoved, .childAdded].forEach { eventType in
Database.database().reference(withPath: key).observe(eventType) { [weak self, storeEventType] snapshot in ...}
```

I get the complete dataset again.

**What I would like is either**:

1. to **.observe(.childAdded)** and somehow know when all the leaves have completed, at least for this dataset,
2. or to use **.observe(.childAdded)** without receiving an initial dataset of all the leaves, but then I need to work out if I missed anything between the **.observe(.value)** and **.observe(.childAdded)** calls.

I know that I could view the dataset as an endless number of deltas and changes, so therefore there isn’t an **END OF SET**, but updating a UITableView in Swift is easier if I know lots of records are queued, in which case I can call a reloadData() on the UITableview. But, if there are just a few records queued, I prefer to let the tableView animate nicely, a row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When an entire snapshot is loaded, the Firebase SDK fires the `value` event. So even if you use the `child*` events for actually handling the data, you can implement a `value` listener to detect when the loading is done.

Implementing both `child*` and `value` event listeners does **not** double the amount of data that gets load. The Firebase SDK deduplicates the listeners behind the scenes.